# d3 continuous transition for circle pulse

Tags: d3.js

I'm struggling to implement a simple continuous transition in d3 - when I hover over a node, I want the stroke of a different circle (fixed somewhere else on the page) to transition between size 2 and 4, back and forth indefinitely, until hovering ends.

I've found a pretty close post on this here: [Increase and decrease radius of a circle using d3 transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19886834/increase-and-decrease-radius-of-a-circle-using-d3-transition).  Particularly the last comment which links to a continuous pulse effect: http://bl.ocks.org/chiester/11267307.

Based on that implementation, the inside of my node hover function looks like this...

```
d3.selectAll('.fixedCircles').each( 
   function (d) {
       if (d.name == "circleToPulse") { //selects the circle I want to pulse, since there's lots of fixed circles

            //this correctly returns the stroke-width of the circle I want to pulse
            var currentStrokeWidth = d3.select(this).attr("stroke-width"); 

            //if I un-comment this, it will correctly update the circle I want to pulse
            //d3.select(this).transition().duration(500).attr('stroke-width', 15); 

            var theCircle = d3.select(this);                            

            repeat();
            function repeat() {
                theCircle = theCircle.transition()
                         .duration(500)
                         .attr("stroke-width", currentStrokeWidth+2) 
                         .transition()
                         .duration(500)
                         .attr('stroke-width', currentStrokeWidth)
                         .ease('sine')
                         .each("end", repeat);
            }
        }
    }
);
```

With this solution, nothing happens.  I've tried changing the stroke-width sizes in case +2 is too subtle, but still nothing happens.  The reason I'm so confused is that I can correctly update the fixed node stroke width outside of the repeat function as my commented code mentions.

Really appreciate any thoughts from anyone on what I might have done wrong here - Thanks!

Comment: damn, sorry!  It was a stupid string versus int thing - adding the values inside the attr setting (instead of currentStrokeWidth) works perfectly.

Comment: Glad you got it, [your code works for me](http://plnkr.co/edit/9c7rE8cndJxtZXsQCKkA?p=preview)

Comment: you could answer yourself your question then mark it as accepted